# Write/Read intermediate Dataframe works better than cache.. Is this expected behaviour?

Tags: apache-spark

When i write the intermediate DF to csv and read it back as Dataframe and perform operations is faster than I cache the intermeditate df(group_df in below flow) and perform operation on it..

Please see example

```
1. input_df(dataframe) => 20 million records
2. group_df(dataframe) => 27k records
```

### `input_df => group_df => perform operations`

I am trying below options and 3rd looks to be faster.. Can you please explain this behavior.

```
1. group_df.cache()
2. group_df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
3. write the group_df to csv and read it back as dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course! `group_df.cache()` does lazy computation and most often only fragments of the data are stored in memory (and many fragments are removed in LRU fashion). In the latter case, all computation is finished and results were written, so the operations on `groupd_df` data would just need to read from disk.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Is it best practise to store intermediate dataframe to an temp file and read it back for further processing to speed up process..? Any other recommended practise?

Comment: For large datasets where OOM is expected, saving to disk is used as a kind of checkpoint. In other cases where the DAG is not complex `cache` and `write.saveAsTable` hurts the overall performance, especially when cached data is used just once. In the current case, the use of `cache()` depends on `perform operations`